# Detecting number range in class/td/div (change css) - jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, selector

**1#** I am wanting to change the CSS of a TD, Class and div using the selector feature that has a number range. To be specific, I'm wanting to change the css of the results of torrents, torrents that have a seed count of 250-25000, anything less or different will have a separate css attribute. If you can help, I would indeed certainly appreciate it.

**References (neither work):**

```
1. http://jsfiddle.net/fVtaF/4/
2. http://jsfiddle.net/fVtaF/3/
```

**My code for detecting keywords in titles (neither work):**

```
 1. $( '.blah td:contains("250-25000") ') .css( {"display":"none"} );
 2. $(".blah td:contains(255-25000)").css({'color':'red'});
```

**I want this number to be CSS Red (250-25000):**

```
<table id="searchResult">
<td align="right">1024</td>
</table>
```

---

**2#** Also, for my code, how can I modify it to detect keywords with out capitals or not being nessesary, even if the word has capitals?

```
$( '.feed-item-container:contains("Justin Bieber") ') .css( {"display":"none"} );
```

Comment: Are you generating the torrent list or are you parsing an existing one?

Comment: I'm just using jquery to override as an extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your own contains() function in jquery to make the selector text case insensitive.

```
jQuery.expr[':'].contains = function(a, i, m) {
   return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/joey6978/678s8/

As per the first part of your question to select all elements with data between 250 and 25000 you can use the jquery filter function:

```
var tds=$("td").filter(function() {
    if($(this).text()>250&&$(this).text()<25000){
        return this;
    }
});
tds.css({'color':'red'});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/joey6978/fVtaF/6/

Comment: How do I turn that into where I can ".blah TD..." OR "#blah TD..." ?

Comment: you would put it in the filter function selector: instead of $("td").filter(function() {....    it would be    
          
$("td.blah").filter(function() {

Comment: thank you very much, your help means more than I can put to words

Comment: it's a different name

Comment: have an issue with something else simular: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21691063/