# Hiding parent element with selector | with filter function (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, filter, jquery-selectors

**I am wanting to hide search results on http://ThePirateBay.se that contain less than 250 seeds**. My problem is, I am not sure how to use the filter option to detect the seeds element, but also hide the parent element when the number range is detected. The second half doesn't work. Help is appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var tds=$("td").filter(function() {
        if($(this).text()>250&&$(this).text()<25000){
            return this;
        }
    });
    tds.css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#383"});
});


$(document).ready(function(){
    var tds=$("TD > #searchResult TR").filter(function() {
        if($(this).text()>001&&$(this).text()<249){
            return this;
        }
    });
    tds.css( {"opacity":"0.35" , "color":"#777"});
});
```

---

jQuery webpage injector to self test: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jscript-tricks/odialddippdmebbfbflcneemfdglimod (JScript Tricks)

---

P.S, with the 2nd half not working, both parts become non-working.

Answer (score 0):

You must parse text to int before comparing like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var tds = $("td").filter(function() {
        return (+$(this).text() > 250 && +$(this).text() < 25000);
    });
    tds.css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#383"});
});


$(document).ready(function(){
    var tds = $("TD > #searchResult TR").filter(function() {
        return (+$(this).text() > 1 && +$(this).text() < 249);
    });
    tds.css( {"opacity":"0.35" , "color":"#777"});
});
```

Comment: Sorry, its not working only the top part is. It's still not hiding the results with the filter function. I use chrome extension Jscript Tricks, you can try it yourself: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jscript-tricks/odialddippdmebbfbflcneemfdglimod

Comment: maybe this is too difficult for either of us?

Comment: I'm very sorry I was looking for a voip service, no its still not hiding the results with less than 250 seeds sadly but the top part is changing the color.

Comment: the parrent that needs to be hidden is TR

Comment: did you try it with my browser extension

Answer (score 0):

What you'd want to do is use the jquery .parent() function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var tds = $("td").filter(function () {
        if ($(this).text() < 250 || $(this).text() > 25000) {
            return this;
        }
    });
    tds.parent().hide();
});
```

This code will hide all table rows that contain elements with numbers greater than 25000 or less than 250 look at the fiddle.http://jsfiddle.net/joey6978/mwN4L/

Comment: It doesn't remove it correctly, it removes all of them, try it here http://jsfiddle.net/mwN4L/3/ or try using my extension and the code I put on post

Comment: the parrent that needs to be hidden is TR

Comment: The html you are using is weird. The jQuery code is fine.

Comment: how and what html are you referencing?

Comment: `$(document).ready(function () {
    var tds = $("tr .tdseed").filter(function () {
        if ($(this).text() < 0 || $(this).text() < 10) {
            return this;
        }
    });
    tds.parent().hide();
});`